# Can finite sets be non-c.e. depending on how they are presented?

Tags: computability-theory, computer-science, mathematical-philosophy

I ask the question because of the following statement found in Mark Burgin's paper, "Algorithmic complexity of recursive and inductive algorithms", *Theoretical Computer Science* 317 (2004) 31-60 (pg. 34):

> It is usually assumed that any finite set is recursively computable and even decidable.  When a finite set is given by a list, then this is true.  However, this assumption is not valid in a general case when a finite set can be defined by a description [the 'presentation'--my comment].  For instance, let us take the set $X$ of all indices of those Turing machines that have the length of their description less than 1000 and that do not terminate on some input with the length less than 1000.  This set is finite, but it is not recursively computable (enumerable).

The problem I see with Prof. Burgin's statement is that computability theory can be (and is usually) formulated in $ZFC$ (the background set theory) in which all sets (regardless of description) can be well-ordered (it should be noted that well-ordered sets, finite or otherwise, can be identified as lists--see Oliver Deiser's paper, "An Axiomatic Theory of Well-Orderings", *The Review of Symbolic Logic* Volume 4, Issue 2, June 2011, pp. 186-204).  As regards finite sets, the Diaconescu-Goodman-Myhill theorem (taken from nlab)

> The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. The principle of excluded middle
> 2. Finitely indexed sets are projective (in fact, it suffices 2-indexed sets to be projective)
> 3. Finite sets are choice (in fact, it suffices for $2$ to be choice)
>    (Here, a set $A$ is finite or finitely-indexed (respectively) if, for some natural number *n*, there is a bijection or surjection (respectively) {0,...,*n* $-$ 1} $\rightarrow $$A$.  Also, $A$ is projective iff every entire relation from $A$ to $B$ (so that every element of $A$ is related to some element of $B$), for any $B$, contains a function $A$ $\rightarrow$ $B$, while $B$ is choice iff every entire relation from $A$ to $B$, for any $A$, contains a function $A$ $\rightarrow$ $B$.)

suggests that Prof. Burgin's example should lead one to question the principle of excluded middle, much as the following:

> The 2$\uparrow$$\uparrow$$\uparrow$6'th digit in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ = 1

might.

Does it (in the sense that Brouwer's argument against excluded middle would cause one to question it)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Burgin seems to conflate the notion of computability (existence of an algorithm) with a stronger notion such as our knowing an algorithm or existence of a proof that a particular algorithm agrees with the given presentation.

In his example, the finite set $X$ is computable. Indeed, any finite set is computable by a table look-up algorithm. For Burgin's $X$, we don't know the table, so we don't know the algorithm, and we have no effective way to produce the table from the given description of $X$. But that doesn't make $X$ uncomputable; it just says that $X$ doesn't have the stronger properties mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice answer--it is very helpful.  As regards the table look-up algorithm--would it well-order $A$ making it a list?

Comment: Rather, would the table (if one had it) well-order $A$ making it a list?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Our means of expressing a table (or any other algorithm for that matter) involve writing the steps in some linear order, so they would implicitly involve a linear ordering of the set.  Note, though, that the usual notion of a finite set --- existence of a bijection with a proper initial segment of the natural numbers --- also implicitly involves a well-ordering.

Comment: I am wondering, though, if having an effective way to produce the table from the given description of $X$ (in Burgin's example or in any other example, for that matter) is implicit in our understanding

Comment: (cont.) of what it means to 'have an algorithm' for generating a given finite set (Burgin grants that for lists, i.e., well-ordered finite sets, what you say is true --see my quote of his in my question).

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Since Burgin's $X$ is a set of natural numbers, it has a standard well-ordering, the usual $<$ relation on natural numbers. This is quite different from being *given* as a list. So I don't see much connection between this issue and choice sets or projective sets.

Comment: in another direction: It may be reasonable to try to define computability of presentations of sets (as opposed to computability of sets), but I don't yet see any natural way to do so. It seems to require an arbitrary decision about how much "work" is allowed on the way from the presentation to the algorithm. (Consider, for example, the set of orders of sporadic simple groups, presented as I've just said.)

Comment: Well, Burgin states this as follows:  "It is usually assumed that any finite set is recursively computable and even decidable.  When a finite set is _given by a list_ [my emphasis], then this is true."  Is a finite set given as a list not projective (if not, why not)?

Comment: Projectivity is a property of a set, not of how it's given. In ZF, it's provable that all finite sets are projective. In intuitionistic higher order logic (the internal logic of topoi), th same is true for K-finite sets $F$ in which the equality relation is decidable (i.e., the diagonal is complemented in $F\times F$) but not for general K-finite sets.

Comment: Would the fact that it is provable in $ZF$ that all finite sets are projective be because for $ZF$, the law of excluded middle holds (via the Diaconescu-Goodman-Myhill theorem)?  Also, what is the structural distinction between "$K$-finite sets $F$ in which the equality relation holds is decidable" and $K$-finite sets in general (other than for the $K$-finite sets $F$ in which the equality relation is decidable, the diagonal is complemented in $F$ $\times$ $F$ in the internal logic of topoi)?

Comment: In a topos with a natural number object $N$, "K-finite" is equivalent to "surjective image of $\{x\in N:x<k\}$ for some $k\in N$" while "K-finite with decidable equality" is equivalent to "bijective image of $\{x\in N:x<k\}$ for some $k\in N$." The crucial set in Diaconescu's proof, $\{a,b\}$ where we're unsure whether $a=b$, is K-finite but doesn't have decidable equality. Hence the distinction at the end of my previous comment.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.   As regards the crucial set in Diaconescu's proof, {$a$, $b$} "where we're unsure whether $a$ = $b$" (being $K$-finite but not having decidable equality), is that the unique set not having decidable equality, or are there arbitrary n-element sets not having decidable equality as well (and how does one determine that they don't have decidable equality)?

Comment: Once a set lacks decidable equality, so does every superset. But I don't think it makes sense to talk about n-element sets that lack decidable equality, at least if n is supposed to be a natural number. For example, we cannot say (constructively) that Diaconescu's {a,b} is a 1-element set or a 2-element set, because we don't know which alternative holds.

Comment: True enough.  If the Axiom of Choice holds, under what conditions does Diaconescu's {$a,$ $b$} become a 1-element or 2-element set (according to Diaconescu, in topoi/toposes, "subobjects do not have honest complements-[they have pseudocomplements--my comment taken from his paper, pg.176.  How does that relate to not knowing which alternative holds, if at all?])?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Well if AC holds, then we have the law of the excluded middle, so we do know whether Diaconescu's $\{a,b\}$ has one element or two (and subobjects have honest complements).

Comment: So that means that if one assumes LEM that (by the Diaconescu-Goodman-Myhill Theorem) that every n-element Diaconescu set has decidable equality and that is the reason we can recognize finite sets?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin What does "we can recognize finite sets" mean?

Comment: What does it mean to say that "we cannot say ( constructively) that Diaconescu's set is a 1-element set or a 2-element set, because we don't know which alternative holds"?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Constructively, to assert a disjunction, one must be able to assert one of the disjuncts.

Comment: True enough, but that doesn't answer my question.  Without LEM, is it possible that _neither_ of the disjuncts can be asserted (I seem to recall that Brouwer asserted that very thing, i.e. that given either $a$ $\lor$ $\neg$$a$, there are circumstances in which neither $a$ nor $\neg$$a$ can be asserted.  Is that also the case with Burgin's example?)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I thought I did answer your question, but, more explicitly, to say that "we cannot say (constructively) that Diaconescu's set is a 1-element set or a 2-element set" means that we cannot say (constructively) that Diaconescu's set is a 1-element set and also we cannot say (constructively) that Diaconescu's set is a 2-element set. This situation occurs because we cannot say that the truth-value (or proposition) used in defining that set is true or false.

Comment: Why would that not be the the case with Burgin's example?

Comment: Burgin's example $X$ shares with Diaconescu's $D=\{a,b\}$ the property that I can't say what its cardinality is. But the reasons are quite different. We don't know what the members of $X$ are, but we can tell whether two given members are equal (because they're natural numbers). We know what the members of $D$ are ($a$ and $b$) but we can't tell whether they're equal.

Comment: Given what you wrote in your last comment, would you say that the Diaconescu set {$a$, $b$} is recursively enumerable?